# VBA: Search for a value in a column, find the next cell that match the value if adjacent cell not empty

Tags: vba, excel

I'm pretty newbie at coding in vba (i'm actually learning on the spot as i've been required to do it so), and I'm having a little trouble getting this right.

What I need is to be able to search for a value {clave} and then insert the current date into the adjacent cell, but I haven't found the way to do it without having it overwrite the very first match.

At first I thought I could do it with a Loop, but I can't quite put my finger on it and I've been running in circles.

Is I haven't found the solution, I just left it as it is, but heres my code:

```
Private Sub buscarbtn_Click()
Dim clv1
Dim rnng As Range

clv1 = clavebx.Value

'Insert date
prontuario1.Range("V:Z").Find(what:=clv1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, -6).Value = Date


'This isn't really relevant, just calling some data into the userform
busbox.Value = Hoja4.Range("D7").Value
mrcbox.Value = Hoja4.Range("D5").Value
corridabox.Value = Hoja4.Range("D8").Value
namebox.Value = Hoja4.Range("D4") & " - " & Hoja4.Range("D6")
fechabox.Value = Date

End Sub
```

And a quick look at my table so you can picture what I'm trying to do.

[image: Table]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you want to search for an ID in column `Clave` (X), and if you find it insert the current date in the same row in Column R?

Comment: yes, exactly, i sorted it out already but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you found the CLAVE ID check if the cell value is empty, if not empty place  the date value.

```
Private Sub buscarbtn_Click()

Dim clv1 As String
Dim rnng As Range

Dim clave_found As Range

clv1 = clavebx.Value

'Insert date

Set clave_found = prontuario1.Range("V:Z").Find(what:=clv1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, -6)

With clave_found
    If .Value = vbNullString Then
        .Value = Date
    Else
        MsgBox "The [CLAVE] ID found with date: " & .Value
    End If

End With

'This isn't really relevant, just calling some data into the userform
busbox.Value = Hoja4.Range("D7").Value
mrcbox.Value = Hoja4.Range("D5").Value
corridabox.Value = Hoja4.Range("D8").Value
namebox.Value = Hoja4.Range("D4") & " - " & Hoja4.Range("D6")
fechabox.Value = Date

End Sub
```